# Chatbot won't respond

Tags: java, chatbot

I am trying to create a chatbot program but my issue is that, when I run the program, it exits right after the sentence is typed.

```
        import java.util.*;

public class Mina{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      ai();
   }

   public static void ai(){
      greeting();
      conversation();
   }

   public static void greeting(){
      System.out.println("Hello. I am Mina.");
   }

   public static void conversation(){
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      String chat = console.nextLine();
      if(!chat.equalsIgnoreCase("\bBye\b") || !chat.equalsIgnoreCase("\bBye.\b")){
         keywords(chat);
      }
   }

   public static void keywords(String word){
      if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bHello\b") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bHello.\b")){
         System.out.println("What do you want to talk about?");
         keywords(word);
      }else if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bMr. Smith\b") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bMr. Smith.\b")){
         System.out.println("I bet he is a nice teacher.");
         keywords(word);
      }else if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bBye\b") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bBye.\b")){
         System.exit(0);
      }
      return;
```

This is what I get:
[Mina's Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsHWD.png)

I previously had my code loop by placing `keyword();` at the end of the method.

```
}else if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bBye\b") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("\bBye.\b")){
     System.exit(0);
   }
   keyword(word);
   return;
```

If anyone has any ideas on what I can possibly do to fix this problem, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to make it work in a fashion where it will ask the user to input a new line until they say "Bye". This is achieved by using the `while` loop as shown:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mina{
public static void main(String[]args){
  ai();
}

public static void ai(){
  greeting();
  conversation();
}

public static void greeting(){
  System.out.println("Hello. I am Mina.");
}

public static void conversation(){
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  String chat = console.nextLine();
  while(!(chat.equalsIgnoreCase("Bye") || chat.equalsIgnoreCase("Bye."))){
     keywords(chat);
chat = console.nextLine();
  }
System.exit(0);
}

public static void keywords(String word){
  if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello.")){
     System.out.println("What do you want to talk about?");
  }else if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("Mr. Smith") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("Mr. Smith.")){
     System.out.println("I bet he is a nice teacher.");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this option but it wound up as an infinite loop that did not respond.

Comment: Try the edited answer, I hadn't tested my previous answer.. This works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still is stuck in an infinite loop and will not reply.
I just tried a `do while` but it was the same way.

Comment: That is impossible. I just tried this again, and it worked. Did you copy my latest code? Copy the whole file..

Comment: Okay, I'll try doing the whole thing when I get to a computer with jGrasp.

Comment: Thank you, it works now that I've used this as my base code.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)?